# Why Gitbash console shows my user Chopped as the default Windows Username even after I changed it?

Tags: git

I am currently taking a Git course and just recently installed Git to my computer, however Git-Bash is displaying the default bugged user from windows that chops the last letter out of it, i managed to change the user folder name and Environment variable long time ago, however this is coming up just now with git, any ideas why this happens?

Comment: How did you change the user folder name and environment variable? Do they correctly represent the actual username you log into Windows with?

Comment: Setting an administrator account, renaming the folder and searching for that register, algo replaced almost al registers containing old username. I don't know if i might be missing something else

Comment: I'm afraid that if you went into Windows with a hacksaw to change your username, all bets are off.

Comment: I managed to fix it, the environment variable %USERNAME% remained misspelled, all i had to do was change the username on netplwiz and now it is fixed, thanks for your help anyway :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix it, the environment variable %USERNAME% remained misspelled, all I had to do was change the username on netplwiz and now it is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

If this is on Windows, try and open a CMD in which you would set a simplified PATH, for testing.

```
set PATH=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
set GH=C:\path\to\git
set PATH=%GH%\bin;%GH%\usr\bin;%GH%\mingw64\bin;%PATH%
```

Then, in that same CMD session, type `git bash` and see if the resulting bash session exhibits the same problem.

Comment: Thanks for answering so soon, I did this, however it is returning that bash is not a git command, any idea why?

Comment: @CamiloPenagos That means the GH environment variable does not reflect the proper Git installation folder. For instance: `set "GH=C:\Program files\Git"`. Double-check where Git is installed. Then repeat those set commands in a fresh CMD session.

Comment: So I am aiming to that folder since it is the same on my pc, still nothing, but I ran just `set` on CMD and I just realized System variable USERNAME remains default with the issue I explained, I guess that's why since git is aiming to \u, by any chance you know how to change that?